# Is it possible to force beamer to automatically create frames for the excessive data (in long table)?

Tags: beamer, longtable

I have a long table and all are important for sure.
It will be tedious if I do trial and error adjustment for the excessive rows.

Shortly speaking, how to force beamer to automatically create frames for the excessive data (in long table)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{title}

\begin{longtable}{cc}
fooooooooooo & Bar\\ 
fooooooooooo & Bar\\ 
fooooooooooo & Bar\\ 
...
\end{longtable}
\end{frame}
```