# beamer: best way to span long enumerations on different frames

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate

I have a question about `beamer` and enumerations. Which is the best way in `beamer` to split a long enumeration in such a way that each main point has its own frame?

I already found [this related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142/how-can-i-make-an-enumerate-list-start-at-something-other-than-1) but I was wondering about the possibility for a cleaner solution.
There's also [this other one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/is-it-possible-to-force-beamer-to-automatically-create-frames-for-the-excessive), but I would like to keep control of frame breaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may define your own enumeration list using `enumerate` and (re)storing the counter:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{cenumerate}{%
  \enumerate
  \setcounter{\@enumctr}{\csname saved@\@enumctr\endcsname}%
}{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname saved@\@enumctr\endcsname{\the\value{\@enumctr}}%
  \endenumerate
}
\newenvironment{cenumerate*}{%
  \enumerate
}{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname saved@\@enumctr\endcsname{\the\value{\@enumctr}}%
  \endenumerate
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{cenumerate*}% starting a new continous enumerate
  \item 1st
  \item 2nd
  \item 3rd
  \item 4th
  \end{cenumerate*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{cenumerate}
  \item 5th
  \item 6th
  \item 7th
  \item 8th
  \end{cenumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{cenumerate}
  \item 9th
  \item 10th
  \item 11th
  \item 12th
  \end{cenumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But this would fail, if you use step by step enumerations like:

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{cenumerate}
  \item 5th
  \item<2-4> 6th
  \item<3-4> 7th
  \item<4> 8th
  \end{cenumerate}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Schweinebacke, it's a really nice solution. I tried that new environment of yours and it seems to be exactly what I was searching for. The step by step issue isn't really a problem for me, I don't use it very often.

Answer (score 13):

This allows a frame break at 80% of the page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.8,t]{title}{}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item 1st
  \item 2nd
  \item 3rd
  \item 4th
  \item 5th
  \item 6th
  \item 7th
  \item 8th
  \item 9th
  \item 10th
  \item 11th
  \item 12th
  \item 13th
  \item 14th
  \item 15th
  \item 16th
  \item 17th
  \item 18th
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Herbert, but it seems to me that with your solution I completely lose control on the frame breaks. Beamer puts them as soon as it lacks space in the current one. I would like to have full, manual control instead.

Comment: @Riccardo: You may use `\framebreak` to add manual frame breaks. This would top align the partial list before the frame break.

Comment: @Riccardo: use `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.7,t]` if you want it at 70% of the page