# Itemize environment too big for one frame in beamer

Tags: page-breaking, itemize

In the end of my presentation, I have a section with open questions in the form of an itemize environment. The \item-s of this environment are just too many to fit in one frame. How can I force the itemize environment to continue to the next frame, or make the frame probably two pages? What is a good solution for this problem? I can always end it and start again in next page. Is there anything more delicate? I tried \pagebreak without success.

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38021

Comment: To get something more delicate, you could show each item click by click and let the older items white out. When you show the last item, the first two items already have vanished and get replaced by the upcoming next item. Like this, the reader always sees the last view items. Or, easier, you add one more item per frame and when filled, move them up like a teleprompter. One item disappears in the top, one appears at the bottom. Easy to write with a lot of frames. (BTW. Please give us an MWE to play with!)

Comment: Which one? The link, the whiting out or the teleprompter? Shall I write an answer or do you want to close your question?